# How can I calculate a span's offset inside preformated text?

Tags: html, text, offset

How can I calculate the offset of the first char of the substring `My car is red` relative to beginning of the predefined text (`Burguer rocks.`)?

```
<pre id="pref-text">
    Burguer rocks. <span id="highlight-0">Without cheese please.</span>
    Pizzaaaaaa time! <span id="highlight-1">My car is red.</span> blablabla.
</pre>
```

Comment: Do you mean the `x, y` position of the span, relative to its parent? Or do you mean the position of the first char in the substring "My car is red", relative to the beginning of the "Berguer rocks... blablabla" string?

Comment: the position on the first char of the substring relative to the beginning of the text

Answer (score 0):

> The **HTMLElement.offsetLeft** read-only method returns the number of pixels that the *upper left corner of the* current element is offset to the left within the [HTMLElement.offsetParent](/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent) node.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

#### To answer your question

> How can I calculate the offset of "My car is red"?

Use the javascript Element's  `.offsetLeft` property.

```js
alert(document.getElementById('highlight-1').offsetLeft);
```

```html
<pre id="pref-text">
Burguer rocks. <span id="highlight-0">Without cheese please.</span>
Pizzaaaaaa time! <span id="highlight-1">My car is red.</span> blablabla.

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that:

```
var span = document.getElementById('highlight-1');

var offset = 0;
var nextBlock = span.previousSibling;

while (nextBlock != null){
    offset = offset + nextBlock.textContent.length;
    nextBlock = nextBlock.previousSibling;
}
```